# to optimize combination performance in python

Tags: python, numpy, numba, array-broadcasting

I am trying to work out a solution, to find out the combinations which could best matching (or as close as possible) to a target

For example: There are 3 groups of choices. each group consists with a combination of a range of letters. Each letter represents a list of 4 elements:

e.g.

```
Group X => A:[1,2,3,4], B:[2,3,4,5], C:[2,4,5,1], D:[5,2,3,1]
Group Y => E:[21,2,33,24], F:[2,13,4,45], G:[2,4,5,21], H:[15,2,23,1]
Group Z => J:[0,2,0,4], K:[2,31,4,0], L:[20,0,0,1], M:[0,2,0,1]
```

There are no limitation for the repeats of each letter. Each use of letter would add up the value.

E.g.

```
AA E K  => [1,2,3,4] + [1,2,3,4] + [21,2,33,24] + [2,31,4,0] = [25,37,43,32]
```

If target is = [30, 37, 43, 32], then we know, this choice of combination is [5,0,0,0] difference. And this would update the benchmark for calculation termination.

As the calculation for the combination are heavy as the choice of the letters increase. I have produced cache files, which stores the combination and its correspondence values in dicts.

```
RGoupX = {"AA":[2,4,6,8],"AB":[4,6,8,10].......} 
RGoupY = {"FG":[4,17,9,66],"GGG":[6,12,15,63].......}
RGoupZ = {......}
```

and then

```
for k1,v1 in RGoupX.items():
    for k2,v2 in RGoupY.items():
        for k3,v3 in RGoupZ.items():
            if target-(v1+v2+v3) == [0,0,0,0]:
               print ("found", k1, k2, k3)
```

The performance is very slow, and very memory consuming. Is there any smarter way and much more effective way to have this done?

Kind regard

Comment: This looks like subset-sum which is known to be NP-complete but with a pre-computation that generate a big input resulting in a huge computation time (and clearly exponential). How big is the a realistic input? Note that Numba and parallelism may help a bit but no more than a relatively small factor compared to the computational cost (and so probably not enough).

Comment: The reason why having a cache is because this function would be reused for many times. And I guess, to load the cache file would be much less hassle than calculation. 
I am doing filtering at each add up, if the current result is way over the benchmark, then would know this choice is not good and would terminate the calculation for the rest of adding up.
I have also partitioned the cache file by its axis value. so the function could know which range of the cache file are good and not over the target. some files are huge, could reach 1G ( I am trying to avoid to use it)

Comment: What is your optimal goal ? Is it the smallest total difference, the smallest maximum difference, the fewest values that are different ?  Also, when you say "a range of letters" from a group does that mean that you can use ABC but not AD from the first group ? (or do you mean any arbitrary selection of letters from each group with possible repetition).  Also, do you need to use at least one letter per group ? And are all of the values positive ?

Comment: The goal is to find the closest to the target. the result could be more than 1 with the same difference. I mean... the combination for group X could be like [A, B, C, D, AA, AB ....... AAA, AAB, AAC....... DDDDDDD].